# camel showing negative in flight exchanges in hawtio

Tags: apache-camel, hawtio

I am using camel version 2.24.1. I am reading a CSV and sending those records to the HTTP endpoint with the jetty client. the problem is on hawtio when I look at how many exchanges are in flight, it always shows a negative number. Does anyone why this is happening

[image]

Comment: Can you check the number with JConsole?  If you see the same number, then the issue is in Camel counting the inflight numbers.

Comment: Does anybody know why negative numbers are shown? I've got the same problem using camel-k with prometheus metrics for some routes only.